# Stata - generate date variable from days count

Tags: date, stata

I want to generate a `date` variable starting from a count of the day and a starting date: I have a rolling cross-section with an integer variable that indicates the count of days since the survey was initially fielded. I also know this actual date. So, theoretically I should be able to generate a proper data variable, but I find no reference for this anywhere in the documentation.

Immagine I have one month of observations (in my case I have hundreds of observations for each day, but the problem is the same in this simplified case):

```
set obs 30
gen day=_n
```

I also know that day 1 is e.g. 12th of March 2015.
How do I generate a daily `date` variable that ranges from 12th of March to the 11th of April?

Comment: Stata handling of dates and times is well explained in their documentation. If you have not already done so, it would benefit you to work your way through the guidance in help datetime, which is without a doubt the most visited documentation on my system, with the second-most-visited being Chapter 24 (Working with dates and times) of the Stata User's Guide PDF available from the PDF Documentation item on Stata's Help menu. Before working with dates and times, any Stata user should read the very detailed Chapter 24 thoroughly. In your example `day+daily("1/8/2015","MDY")` perhaps.

Comment: Correcting the above, since I can no longer edit it, `day+daily("11/3/2015","DMY")` perhaps.

Comment: I think `help datetime` would also be a good place to have a read.

Answer (score 1):

Good comments to read the help file for dates/times. This is also my most-read help file, which suggests that it may not be that approachable for new users.

I use `mdy()` to determine the days since 1/1/1960, which I add to your `day` variable. There are may ways to do this, but this should get you started.

```
clear
set obs 30
gen day=_n

generate dayCalendar = (day - 1) + mdy(3, 12, 2015)
format dayCalendar %td
```

This gives you the following.

```
. list in 1/5

     +-----------------+
     | day   dayCale~r |
     |-----------------|
  1. |   1   12mar2015 |
  2. |   2   13mar2015 |
  3. |   3   14mar2015 |
  4. |   4   15mar2015 |
  5. |   5   16mar2015 |
     +-----------------+
```